# Undefined variable Error Laravel only on Live Server

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a custom Laravel Project.

I am getting following error:

```
Undefined variable: count_pandding (View: /domains/web4/html/manager/app/views/admin/home.blade.php)
```

but strange thing is this error does not show in localhost and works perfectly only in life server.

I have tried passing variables in 2 ways:

```
public function home()
{

    $count_pandding = \Postjob::where('approve',0)->get()->count();
    $count_disapprove = \Postjob::where('approve',2)->get()->count();
    $count_approve = \Postjob::where('approve',1)->get()->count();
    $count_expire = \Postjob::where('approve',3)->get()->count();

    return View::make('admin.home',  compact('count_pandding','count_disapprove','count_approve','count_expire'));

}
```

and 2nd way

```
 public function home()
{

    $data['count_pandding'] = \Postjob::where('approve',0)->get()->count();
    $data['count_disapprove'] = \Postjob::where('approve',2)->get()->count();
    $data['count_approve'] = \Postjob::where('approve',1)->get()->count();
    $data['count_expire'] = \Postjob::where('approve',3)->get()->count();

    return View::make('admin.home',$data);
}
```

None of it works in Life Server! But works perfectly in Localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Please review [Larvel Response](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses)

The second parameter of make is an array with key value bindings. I find it strange that this is working on your local machine.

Try

```
return View::make('admin.home', [
   'count_pandding' => $count_pandding,
   ...
]);

Or

return View::make('admin.home')->withCountPannding($count_pannding); 
//this becomes $countPannding in your view
```

Update:

```
return View::make('admin.home')->with($keyValueArray); 
//should also translate into $key inside the view.
```

Comment: return View::make('admin.home', ['count_pandding' => $count_pandding,'count_disapprove' => $count_disapprove,'count_approve' => $count_approve,'count_expire' => $count_expire]);   works in localhost not live server. i have even tried creating $data array and passing using make  , return View::make('admin.home')->withCountPannding($count_pannding);  works but how to pass all datas?

Comment: Really weird, what's your local php version vs servers php version?

Comment: Local: 5.5.12  / Server : 5.4.16

Comment: Is it the only var it doesn't find  (if so check spelling). PHP version should be ok, check my updated answer

Comment: it cannot find all the variables.